# Prevent Visual Studio Code from opening up when Open in Terminal option is selected

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, right-click

When I right click on a folder in the path bar and select the Open in Terminal option a VS Code window pops up instead of the classical terminal window. If I delete VS Code then the action is performed correctly and the terminal opens up. How do I disable this extremely annoying feature of VS Code?
My mac runs Ventura 13.1 and VS Code version is 1.74.3
[image: right click on path bar -> open in terminal]

Comment: I'm also having this issue since some weeks. Still be solution except reinstalling (or installing iTerm2, which also don’t like :)).

Comment: @gernophil The following answer may have the answers you are looking for. This functionality seems to be a service provided by Terminal. I'm not sure how that got transferred to VSCode. I wish I could help more, but I can't get this problem to happen on my own device, so I'm at a dead end there. https://superuser.com/a/379354/1832631

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and spent hours with lsregister and duti to no avail. I finally fixed it by installing iTerm2, making iTerm2 the default terminal app, and then uninstalling iTerm2. Also, this seems to be user account related, because I created a new account installed VS Code, used Open in Terminal and Terminal.app opened.